# Append a new line in a Outlook mailitem html body

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, outlook, add-in

I need some help formatting text in a mail item html body.
I want to add more messages in the mail body but on all messages on different lines. 
It may be obviously easy but idk I have a lapsus or something.

Format I want:

```
-Message.
-Message.
-Message.
```

Format I get now:

```
Message,Message,Message.
```

Code:

```
StringBuilder infoMessage = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string element in form.InfoMessages)
{
infoMessage.AppendLine(element);
}
mailItem2.HTMLBody = infoMessage;
```

`InfoMessages` is a `List<string>`

***Edited for a better understanding***

Comment: a `\n` in HTML probably won't show up. Try using `<br />`

Answer (score 4):

It's a HTML body so just use HTML tags:

```
StringBuilder infoMessage = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string element in form.InfoMessages)
{
    infoMessage.AppendLine("<p>" + element + "</p><br/>");
}
mailItem2.HTMLBody = string.Format("{0} <br/> {1}",infoMessage,mailItem2.HTMLBody);
```

Comment: Why have you decided to make the elements links?

Comment: Just as example, now its a paragraph if you feel better with it.

Comment: Ty for help +1 @Momo

Answer (score 1):

HTML should use `<br/>` for new lines, not `\n` (which would apply to the plain text body).

Try this change instead:

```
StringBuilder infoMessage = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string element in form.InfoMessages)
{
    infoMessage.AppendLine(element + "<br/>");
}

mailItem2.HTMLBody = string.Format("{0} <br/>{1}",infoMessage,mailItem2.HTMLBody);
```

---

Disclaimer: `<br/>` isn't the only way to separate elements on to new lines, but it seems most applicable in this instance.

Comment: @ musefan I edited the question for a better understanding. Not \n was a problem for me the infoMessages itself.

Comment: @BogdanSorin: I don't understand, does my answer not give you what you need? What is wrong with it that isn't what you expect?

Comment: Tested few more cases and it worked. Thanks for help. @musefan